# Change value of TD with jquery

Tags: jquery

This is the structure of my html table :

```
<table id="dates_stages_comp">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>TEST</td>
  <td>Henry</td>
  <td>313278</td>
  <td>PHAR5S-D</td>
  <td>
       <select id="sel_type_stage_comp#313278">
  </td>
 <td>45 jours</td>
</tr>
```

I try to put a new value in the second TD (45 jours) after the one who contains the select with this code:

```
$('#dates_stages_comp tr td:nth-child(9)').html(retour);
```

The problem is that all TD change and not only the actual row.

Have you an idea please ?

Comment: Your numbers are all over the place.  To me it looks like you are trying to update the last TD not the 2nd?  You need to be a little clearer in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target just that one `td`, you want to find it based on the `select` element's `id` (since it has one):

```
$('select[id="sel_type_stage_comp#313278"]').closest('td').next().html(retour);
```

Note that I used an attribute selector rather than and ID selector; you *could* use an ID selector but you'd have to figure out what the escape is for the `#` in it...

Comment: I *think* Sizzle still allows simple backslash quoting for metacharacters, but I haven't tried messing with that in the modern `querySelector` world.

Comment: Thank you, it works.  I added a next() to get the awaiting resulta.